# mysql select subquery with the same table

Tags: mysql, subquery

Is it possible to select subquery on same table, i.e.

```
...(select * from tableA a, select somecolumnA, max(somecolumnB) from tableA group by somecolumnA) b...
```

... indicates the other queries in the other tables using left joins etc.
will this cause any slowness in mysql?

Actually, I am having error "lost connection to mySQL server during query". I am looking if this part is actually causing the problem.

Comment: Yes,  possible. I did it a lot.

Comment: Hmms. I had the error because I was querying with something else, i.e. select anocolA, anocolB, anocolC, anoColD, (select * from tableA a, someColumnA, max(somecolumnB) from tableA group by somecolumnA) b left join tableC c on a.anocolA = c.somecol where ..........